# Maximize an Nx7 rectangle of words step-by-step

Tags: optimization, scrabble

In Scrabble, you score points for *each* new word you make on your turn. Therefore, on a board of `AIRLINE` and holding a rack of `FLOATED`, instead of playing

```
FLOATED
      AIRLINE
```

to score only the points for `FLOATED` and `DA`, you should play the seven-letter overlap

```
FLOATED
AIRLINE
```

because you score points for the two-letter words `FA`, `LI`, `OR`, `AL`, `TI`, `EN`, and `DE` in addition to that for `FLOATED`.

There are many other such 2-layer bingo (seven-tile) overlaps.

**Puzzle:** Try to find an N-layer bingo overlap and **maximize N**. **All words formed on each turn must be valid**. You're encouraged to post an answer when you can beat an existing N. (Currently, N=2 from the above discussion)

The tiebreak is the sum of Scrabble points of all turns (assuming a board with no double/triple-letter/word squares).

**Detailed rules:**

- You're playing Scrabble by yourself (no opponent).
- Each turn (after the first) must be connected to the words already formed.
- Words formed on all turns, including intermediate turns, must be in the Collins Scrabble Words (CSW) (2019) lexicon. (I chose CSW because it is bigger; 2019 is just the latest one that I can get my hands on. Let me know if this makes a big difference.)

The total set of tiles played must not exceed the [Scrabble Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrabble_letter_distributions) (for example, you cannot play 4 Z's because there is only 1 Z and 2 blanks).

**Hints**:

> Suppose there are 3 words A, B, and C and you want to form the overlap "A on top of B on top of C". You may find that the order of playing matters: i.e. playing "C then B then A" doesn't work but playing "A then B then C" works.

> You can check the official Zyzzyva app to verify your words, or even download the full list of 279,496 words, though downloading the words may or may not be helpful.

Comment: Are computer-aided searches permitted?

Comment: @bobble yes, although the search space might be bigger than you think :D